# Is there a Master Controller for The Sims 3 Patch 1.62?

Tags: the-sims-3

I really want to download this mod known as Master Controller. On 'nraas' website the older versions for this mod are given. But the version directly skips from 1.57 to 1.63. Does this mean that there is no version of the mod for 1.62? 
Which version of the mod should I download?

Comment: Surely this question would be a better fit on this website you speak of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you not update to 1.63? If not, I would just use the 1.57 version.

Comment: I have downloaded and installed both versions of the mod. Both work just fine.